# How can I use Linq to XML to parse an XML string and locate all nodes with a value that starts with a specified letter?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given a string of XML text like

```
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<directory dirname=\"c\">" +
            "<directory dirname=\"documents\">" +
                "<directory dirname=\"daves projects 2015\" />" +
                "<directory dirname=\"vics projects 2015\" />" +
                "<directory dirname=\"daves projects 2014\" />" +
            "</directory>" +
            "<directory dirname=\"daves projects archive\" />" +
        "</directory>";
```

What is the current preferred way to parse this string using Linq to XML so that it returns a list of directory names that start with "dave". Or is there a better way than using Linq to XML

I need an result that is a list of strings like the following;

daves projects 2015

daves projects 2014

daves projects archive

I tried using the following;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml =
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<directory dirname=\"c\">" +
            "<directory dirname=\"documents\">" +
                "<directory dirname=\"daves projects 2015\" />" +
                "<directory dirname=\"vics projects 2015\" />" +
                "<directory dirname=\"daves projects 2014\" />" +
            "</directory>" +
            "<directory dirname=\"daves projects archive\" />" +
        "</directory>";

    var Folders = ParseXmlString(xml, "dave");
    foreach (XElement name in Folders)
        Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
}



private static List<XElement> ParseXmlString(string xmlStr, string searchValue)
{
    List<XElement> result = new List<XElement>();

    try
    {
        var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
        result = str.Elements("directory").Where(x => x.Element("dirname").Value.StartsWith(searchValue)).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But result is always empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a recursive function.  Flat functions will not return the the directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function as below...

1. In the calling method, change the type as

   ```
   foreach (XAttribute name in Folders)
   ```
2. Change the ParseXmlString as below.

   ```
   private static List<XAttribute> ParseXmlString(string xmlStr, string searchValue)    
   {
           List<XAttribute> result = new List<XAttribute>();    
           try
           {
               XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

               result = doc.Descendants("directory")
                           .Attributes("dirname")
                           .Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith("d"))
                           .ToList();                
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw ex;
           }
           return result;
   }
   ```

Let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

In VB, using XElement it would be

```
    Dim xe As XElement = XElement.Parse(xml)
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of String) = From el In xe...<directory>
                                       Where el.@dirname.StartsWith("dave")
                                       Select el.@dirname
```